# menu alignment in react-bootstrap dropdown doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a dropdown component, adding `align="right"` doesn't do anything, am I doing it wrong?

```
const SelectGroup = (props) => {
  return (
    <Dropdown>
      <Dropdown.Toggle id="dropdown-toggle" className="groupDropdown">
        Group
      </Dropdown.Toggle>

      <Dropdown.Menu align="right" id="dropdown-menu">
        <Dropdown.Item id="dropdown-item">1</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item id="dropdown-item">2</Dropdown.Item>
      </Dropdown.Menu>
    </Dropdown>
  );
};
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont't know which react-bootstrap version you was using, but for react-bootstrap 5 the valid values are "start" and "end" (not "right"):

https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/dropdowns/#dropdown-menu-props